# How to set the redis timeout waiting for the response with pipeline in redis-py?

Tags: python, redis, response, pipeline, redis-py

In the code below, is the pipeline timeout 2 seconds?

```
client = redis.StrictRedis(host=host, port=port, db=0, socket_timeout=2)
pipe = client.pipeline(transaction=False)
for name in namelist:
    key = "%s-%s-%s-%s" % (key_sub1, key_sub2, name, key_sub3)
    pipe.smembers(key)
pipe.execute()
```

In the redis, there are a lot of members in the set "key". It always return the error as below with the code last:

```
error Error while reading from socket: ('timed out',)
```

If I modify the socket_timeout value to 10, it returns ok.
Doesn't the param "socket_timeout" mean connection timeout? But it looks like response timeout. 
The redis-py version is 2.6.7.

Answer (score 29):

I asked [andymccurdy](https://github.com/andymccurdy) , the author of redis-py, on github and [the answer](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/issues/485) is as below:

> If you're using redis-py<=2.9.1, socket_timeout is both the timeout
>   for socket connection and the timeout for reading/writing to the
>   socket.     I pushed a change recently (465e74d) that introduces a new
>   option, socket_connect_timeout. This allows you to specify different
>   timeout values for socket.connect() differently from
>   socket.send/socket.recv(). This change will be included in 2.10 which
>   is set to be released later this week.

The redis-py version is 2.6.7, so it's both the timeout for socket connection and the timeout for reading/writing to the socket.

Answer (score 3):

It is not connection timeout, it is operation timeout. Internally the socket_timeout argument on StrictRedis() will be passed to the socket's settimeout method.

See here for details: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout

Comment: It depends on the version of redis-py.If you're using redis-py<=2.9.1, socket_timeout is both the timeout for socket connection and the timeout for reading/writing to the socket.